# Change anaconda environment's folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, anaconda

I am by default using python 3.4, but sometimes I have to use python 2, therefore I created an anaconda environment using the following command:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

The command is computed without issue. BUT the folder within which the environment is created is in my user folder and I have a "ë" in the name of this folder (under windows 8 I can't change my user's folder name unfortunately).

Then I try to launch the environment: `conda activate py27` still no problem, but when I try to launch a `jupyter notebook` command (no matter the folder I'm in) I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My question is: how can I get python 2.7 to work given this problem?
If you can give me a way to:

-change the user's folder name under windows 8

-create an anaconda's environment in a different folder

-get the py27 environment to work no matter the "ë" in the anaconda environment's folder path

-get a way to work under python 2.7 without having to install two independant different versions of python

etc...

that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 7:**

Go to the Anaconda folder in the **Start Menu/All Programs** and find there the **Anaconda Prompt** shortcut. Open the shortcut properties. **You will see the "Start in" field pointing to %HOME% (your user folder).** Feel free to change it to whichever folder you want Anaconda to point at.
Cheers.

**Windows 10:**

- Click on the **Windows icon** (left corner) and look for **All Apps**.
- Open down **Anaconda** and look for **Anaconda Prompt** and right-click on it.
- On the Menu look for **More** and then **Open file location**. There you will
  see the Anaconda shortcut.
- Right Click on it and look for **Properties**.
  On the box **Start in:** you will probably see **%HOME%**. Feel free to
  change it to any folder you want.